# Are there any fully managed SQL databases on AWS, if no why not?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services

As far as I am aware there is no DynamoDB equivalent database in transnational SQL land which is fully managed, as in there doesn't exist an SQL database which is implemented with a server-less architecture, every SQL database on AWS right now needs to be deployed to an EC2 instance.

Please correct me if I am wrong otherwise is there any theoretical reason why AWS or a third party does not create a server-less SQL database implementation? Or at least something close to a server-less implementation whereby there is no EC2 instance to manage?

**Edit**
Not sure what @aquinas or others are on about, none of the current RDS services are fully managed. **IMPORTANT NOTE:** It's actually also a question which sometimes comes up in your certification tests:

> Which databases are fully managed?

Then you get a bunch of selections and only **DynamoDB** (atm see accepted answer) is fully managed, which is not a transactional SQL database. @aquinas is entirely incorrect, there is the notion of partially managed (as you would see in the explanation to that question if you were doing a practice AWS test when you get it wrong), in that you must specify when AWS should patch your database, how it should behave when it fails etc. Current RDS services don't have the elasticity as DyanmoDB and...

**YOU HAVE AN EC2 INSTANCE???!!!??** screen shot attached!

[image]
However [Amazon Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/), brought to my attention from the accepted answer mentions in it's pricing section:

> With Aurora Serverless, there are no instances to manage.

On a final note, these terms are not just semantics, they are important concepts in cloud computing. **Fully Managed** has a meaning, it's not open for interpretation as to what that means in AWS. Just because you use RDS to setup your EC2 instance running your database doesn't make it so. In this setup in the shared responsibility model means you are still controlling the EC2 instance, therefore meaning it is not fully managed!

Comment: Look at https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/.

Comment: RDS doesn't require you to manage an EC2 instance: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Comment: @aquinas sorry you are misinformed you have to deploy all those currently to an EC2 instance, as opposed to specifying your requirements as you would for DynamoDB, but looks like Aurora Serverless is coming!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this question as to why it should be closed pease comment for valid close reason.

Comment: If you were the one voting to close this question can you undo that vote given that you are incorrect in saying RDS is fully manage and there are no instances, both these statements are very false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Right now there is no service available on AWS.

But! Few weeks ago [Amazon Aurora Serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless) was announced and you are able to signup for preview access. So hopefully in the near future AWS supports a managed SQL solution.

Comment: Didn't know about Aurora Serverless that's awesome !!